# How to query date column that contains time values greater than 0:00?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2016

I need to query a date column to return only those dates that have a time value greater than 0:00:00 AM.

So the date of 01/01/2000 0:00:00 would not return but
01/01/2000 12:01:00 AM or 03/04/2009 08:50:23 PM would return

So far I have

```
 select * from test 
 where date > '%0:01%'
```

Obviously this doesn't work

Comment: 12:00:00 is noon by default, and 00:00:00 is midnight (12:00 am). Try this query: ` select * from test where Cast(date as time(3))> '00:00:00.999'`

Comment: can you show some example data and the expected output? which data type is the `date` column?

Comment: Yea sorry i meant midnight.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you all times that are not midnight, but it will include every date/day value at all just as long as the time is not midnight.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE CAST(date AS TIME) > '00:00:00.000'
```